# Inputting and printing values from csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, input

I'm new to Python and hoping someone might be able to give me some pointers on the following-

I have a simple .csv file titled 'Accounts Due. csv' which I wish to read in Python- I've provided the column names and sample rows below.

| Store ID | Account Expiry Date |
| --- | --- |
| 10229 | 01/07/2019 |
| 87393 | 31/10/2019 |
| 70708 | 08/11/2021 |
| 59565 | 24/07/2021 |
| 67453 | 07/01/2020 |

I want to be able to input a number from the Store ID column into the console and have it print the corresponding date from the Account Expiry Date column.

I then want to compare today's date to the printed expiry date and  print either 'okay' or 'account has expired' depending on whether today's date is before or after the account expiry date. I am new to Python- any assistance or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: This site is for specific programming questions only, your question is too broad. Just begin, play around with Python and if you have a specific issue you can ask here with your code.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelButscher, though I have found that the hardest thing when learning programing is knowing what terminology to use. Thus, here's a few things you might want to look into: First, you want to **parse** a csv file. You might want to look into libraries that do that. Secondly, you want python to understand dates. you should look into tools/libraries that allow python to do that. Simply combine both and you have your solution! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple draft to start with.

```py
import datetime

# reading simple and small csvs are easy by hand
with open("mycsv.csv", encoding="utf-8") as fp:  # open the file
    csv_lines = fp.readlines()  # read all line
csv_lines = [line.split(",") for line in csv_lines[1:]]  # split the lines into 'records'.
                                                         # Note, csv_lines[1:] means we skip the header

input_id = input("Enter store id")  # Read the input from the user

for (store_id, exp_date) in csv_lines:  # we iterate through the data
    if store_id == input_id:  # if the ids are the same
        
        # get today's date and parse datetime from the string. Then, we get the date from the datetime object.
        if datetime.date.today() <= datetime.datetime.strptime(exp_date, "%d/%m/%Y\n").date(): 
            print("okay")
        else:
            print("account has expired")
        break
else:
    print("No record found")
```

This might not the best version of this program, but a great start and maybe the most understandable at first. I suggest you to read about everything this code presents.

- [date handling in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)
- [file handling in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)
- [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?#list-comprehensions)
- [control flow in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Comment: Thank you all so much for your explanation, pointers  and suggestions for further reading, It’s much appreciated and has given me a great foundation to get started :) I’m brand new to coding and IT in general and 75% of the battle for me at the moment as Benjamin Chausse says is knowing how to ask the right questions using the right terminology in order to find the resources that are out there to build my own solution. I really appreciate you guys taking the time out to help :)

Comment: Any time! Hope you can use this code to learn Python. Try the code, get familiar with its constructs, and modify it a lot to see what happens when you modify this code. Also, if this answer was helpful, please consider to accept it as an answer.